# AsyncTask not calling doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a button in my application which on click should run AsyncTask but the doInBackground method is not being called, I am trying to connect to my server using okHTTP inside AsyncTask, here is my code,

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
Button button;
public static final String TAG = "aj";
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sendRequest myTask = new sendRequest();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    else
        myTask.execute();
}

private class sendRequest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground");
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = null;
        if (token != null) {
            body = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("Token", token)
                    .build();
        }
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://www.example.com/aj20010319")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I don't know why the doInBackground method is not being called, the logger doesn't log anything regarding it. And if I am correct, it is setup correctly. I tried the solutions in other threads but none is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checked your code in my machine removing the complexities its working fine i pasted the code bellow.
Two thing it can happen

> 1. problem with build version . just call the `myTask.execute()`;remove all the if else
> 2. It might happen with the logcat . if possible make toast from the doInBackground

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

> 3. If you are searching in the logcat it always searches by message not by tag so search by **doInBackground** not by aj

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements View.OnClickListener{
Button button;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    sendRequest myTask = new sendRequest();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
     myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    else
     myTask.execute();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    private class sendRequest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            int i=0;
            while(++i<100)
            {
                Log.i("www", "www");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I don't know how but it started to work automatically, I reverted the code back to original and it's working. Could be some studio issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the class

```
new myTask().execute();
```

Inside the onClickListener

Comment: I think this line does initiate the class, sendRequest myTask = new sendRequest();